# Optional parameter confusion

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

If I have a method something like the following..

```
void Foo (int x, int y = 23, int z=10) 
{
    Console.WriteLine (x); 
}
```

And I pass:  `Foo(20,30)`
which of the the 2 *optional parameters* will get 30?
Also, what if I want to pass 20 to `x` and 30 to `z`?

Comment: Why not give it a try and see? :)

Comment: Why don't you try yourself?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: I did, I get 10,20,10 on passing  Foo(10,20); But what if I want to pass 20 the last one?

Comment: @Arbaaz: You can use the named argument , like Foo(10,z:20)

Comment: @Kjartan: The key insight needed by the OP is the ability to explicitly name parameters.  This is not discoverable via "try it and see." Further, someone who does not know this feature exists will also not know to read the documentation to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the parameters are positional and first-come first-served, so `x` takes `20`, `y` takes `30`, and `z` takes the default of 10. If you want non-positional, you need to be explicit:

```
Foo(20, z: 30);
```

A simple change would let you find out, though:

```
Console.WriteLine ("x={0}, y={1}, z={2}", x, y, z);
```

Comment: So all i need to do is mention the name of the parameter? cool. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"a function...can be called in the standard way by sending arguments... by position, in the order defined by the function."

"A named argument can follow positional arguments... However, a positional argument cannot follow a named argument."

[Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

So as you have not specified any named arguments, Foo(20, 30) will be interpreted entirely positionally, as x and y. z will be left as the default 10.

If you want to specify z and not y, you would invoke like so:

```
Foo(10, z: 30)
```

or

```
Foo(x: 10, z: 30)
```

or

```
Foo(z: 30, x: 10)
```

These all do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's the order of the optional parameters that rules.

With `Foo(20, 30),` y will get 30.

To pass 20 to x and 30 to z, you will have to do `foo(20, z: 30);`

Answer (score 0):

`Foo(20, 30)` is equal to `Foo(20, 30, 10)` (default value is added into a call by compiler). If you want to specify third, but don't want to specify second parameter, you still need to supply some value to a function call `Foo(20, ..., 30)`. Mostly, in such cases, *special values* are defined for second parameter, something like

```
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="y">Y parameter. Can be 0. Default value: 23</param>
    void Foo(int x, int y = 23, int z = 10)
```

so that you will call it `Foo(20, 0, 30)` or, if there is a constant defined, more clearly:

```
const int IGNORED = 0;
...
Foo(20, IGNORED, 30);
```

However, it would be nice to supply not a special but *default* value and this is where you can omit optional parameters completely (as other answers point it out): `Foo(20, z: 30)`, which will be converted by compiler into a call `Foo(20, 23, 30)` (default value is taken for second parameter).